# Javascript text field validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am having difficulty validating a form in javascript. I'm currently checking just a text field and it doesn't work. My code is as followed:

index.html:

```
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
    <title>
        Validation Form
    </title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src ="vForm.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id = "myForm" action ="">
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname"></br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"></br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass1"></br>
        Re-enter password: <input type="password" name="pass2"></br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"></br>
        Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"></br>
        Address: <input type="text" name="add"></br>
        Date: <input type="date" name="date"></br>
        Time: <input type="time" name="time"></br>
        <input type="reset" name="reset">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src ="vFormRun.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

vForm.js:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
    var lname = document.getElementById("lname");
    var pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1");
    var pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2");
    var email = document.getElementById("email");

    if(fname == "")
    {
        alert("Please enter first name")
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

vFormRun.js:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = validateForm;
```

Comment: basic javascript. missed `.value`.

Comment: off-topic: you haven't specified if you're validating the data on the server side as well, but in case you aren't, be aware that JS validation can be bypassed by the user: it can be helpful, but it shouldn't be considered secure. Validate the same data on the server side as well.

Comment: [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?cb=1)

Comment: Here is a great example of where debugging (via Firebug or the equivalent tool in Chrome etc) would be really useful. Put a breakpoint on the line after `var fname = ...` and you would see that the element has a *property* called value with the right thing in. Learn it, save yourself a lot of effort.

Comment: @RASG is correct, should be:  
    `var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;  
     var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;  
     var pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;  
     var pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;  
     var email = document.getElementById("email").value;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("fname");
```

That will only work if you have an element with an ID of `fname`, which you do not.

You can set the ID attribute to an element like so:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
```

Alternatively, you can reference the form elements like this:

```
var fname = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"]
```

Then you want to get it's `value` property when comparing.

```
fname.value
```

---

The `<br>` tag is self closing, so it should be `<br />` instead of `</br>`

Comment: Still, don't let people downvote you! :P Check your answer, it is not correct. I don't understand which illiterate upvoted you. ;) You did the same mistake as the OP did... :)

Comment: There's no need for name calling here.

Comment: @PraveenKumar But they did point out something important - that the elements need an `id` attribute for it to work at all! Still, the function needs to use `.value` as everyone's pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give `.value` to each of it. And also, give an `id` of the same `name`.

```
function validateForm()
{
 var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
 var lname = document.getElementById("lname");
 var pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1");
 var pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2");
 var email = document.getElementById("email");

 if(fname.value == "")
 {
   alert("Please enter first name")
   return false;
 }
 else
 {
   return true;
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution...

```js
function validateForm(form) {
    var fname = form.fname,
        lname = form.lname,
        pass1 = form.pass1,
        pass2 = form.pass2,
        email = form.email;

    if(fname && fname.value === "") {
        alert("Please enter first name");
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Invalid';
        return false;
    }
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Passed';
    return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="" onsubmit="validateForm(this)">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br/>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass1"><br/>
    Re-enter password: <input type="password" name="pass2"><br/>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
    Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"><br/>
    Address: <input type="text" name="add"><br/>
    Date: <input type="date" name="date"><br/>
    Time: <input type="time" name="time"><br/>
    <input type="reset" name="reset">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  <p id="result">
  </p>
</form>
```

There were a few issues here that I corrected.

1. I changed all of the `var` declarations to use one `var` declaration. This is a best practice.
2. In the if statement I added a check for the variable `fname` to make sure it exists and is not null (prevents a null reference error).
3. In the if statement you need to check the `value` attribute of the filed, not the field itself. In your old code if it is blank or not the field should be there and would have always returned true.
4. I changed the comparison to use `===` instead of `==`. When using `==`, if the value is "false" or 0 it will return true. See "[Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)".
5. You were missing a semicolon at the end of the `alert` statement.
6. If the body of the `if` ends with a `return` then you do not need an `else` block. Cuts down the amount of code (downloads faster) and makes it easier to read.

Comment: What was the down vote for? If there is something wrong with the answer I would like to know (via a comment) so that everyone can benefit from better answers.

Comment: Probably because you missed the obvious one: no elements in the form have any IDs so you can't do `getElementById`. All of your other points are valid.

Comment: @sachleen , can you verify that my changes to the example are now causing it work?