# How to force a specific input in text field in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation, input

I need to set three different types of allowed inputs for my application like this:

- running disciplines 00,00
- long running disciplines 00:00,00
- jumping disciplines 0,00

`<%= f.text_field %>` should force an input such as that, is there a way I could do it?

Comment: Have a look at [jQuery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) for masking input fields.  Back this by model format validation on those fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it with `Model validation` along with a `Regular Expression`. So if you are only allowing the given values i.e., '00,00', '00:00,00', '0,00' , you can do:

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_format_of :field_name, :with => /((\A[0]{2}(\,|\:)[0]{2}((\,)[0]{2})*\Z)|(\A[0]{1}(\,)[0]{2}\Z))/i, :message => " is Invalid"
end
```

Check it here http://rubular.com/r/7ZGo0ktlSe

***Update as per the comment from* Xeen:**

If you allow all the digits [0-9], the you can go for the answer below:

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_format_of :field_name, :with => /((\A\d{2}(\,|\:)\d{2}((\,)\d{2})*\Z)|(\A\d{1}(\,)\d{2}\Z))/i, :message => " is Invalid"
end
```

Check http://rubular.com/r/c2Q5K3armn.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, it allows only literaly `00,00`, but if it's, say, `15,22` the it doesn't let it through

Comment: @Xeen: You did not say what all character types you want to allow with the given format. That's why I've considered `00,00` only and not `15,22`.

Answer (score 0):

One way can be to use `JS` functions, put all the validations in that, and show alerts when user tries to submit the `form`. Js function will be like this:

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || other conditions)
  {
  alert("Please enter in THAT format");
  return false;
  }
}
```

and using following `HTML` snippet, you can validate it on submit:

`<input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return validateForm()">`

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663561/javascript-text-field-validation) as well.

Comment: I thought about this aswell, but got stuck at figuring out how to define `00:00,00` to be the right format :)

Comment: You can test this format using a regular expression like `/^\d{2}:\d{2},\d{2}$/.test(x)`